# key wont turn, can't change gear on automatic Plymouth Neon 2000

Tags: starting, key

The key wont turn in ignition switch, I can't change the gear (the button is locked sort of). 2000 Plymouth Neon Automatic. Is there a temporary fix to it? Never had this problem before.

Answer (score 1):

Can you turn the steering wheel? It can be in a lock position. If so, then turn slightly the steering wheel and retry your key.

Comment: Stearing is not locked. The fact that I can't even press the button on the gear, something else is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**This could be cold related**

I have to leave the car at work because I could not turn the key. The next day tried in the morning, but to no avail. Then came in lunch break, made another effort and after a little this and that, the key finally turned. I am thinking this could be cold related.

The temperature has been very cold here (10F-1F).  All drinks in the including cokes had frozen and one of them had bursted with the Can ripped. In the noon, while it was still cold, it was a little bit better and I think that made the difference.